# How to write a view helper that renders works with HAML and ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb, helper, actionview

Hi I am working on a [gem](http://github.com/maca/table_builder) that defines a few view helpers and it heavily relies on concat and capture methods but I've recently discovered it doesn't work with HAML (haven't tested thoroughly, but so far doesn't render concat(nated) stuff).

I read somewhere there was a haml_concat version of concat. So If I just need to change my concat calls to haml_concat calls for it to work with HAML, how can I tell if I am using haml or erb to call the corresponding method?

Can anyone provide an example of a view helper using concat and capture that works with erb and haml?

:)

Comment: I'd check the presense of the `Haml` module? `defined?(Haml)`, and then call the `haml_contact` or the normal `concat` based on that.

Comment: ok, that tells me if the haml gem is required but not if I am using a haml template, maybe haml_concat works even if called from an erb template, will check. Thanks

Comment: Did you find any answer? This would be interesting for me, too.